# Conditionally render components in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and still learning my way around. I have a react page that renders a component that has 5 buttons. I'm trying to render another component based on which button is clicked. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by state usage.
Useful for this goal being useState hook and conditional rendering in React. More info about it: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Example for your question:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [isTextVisible, setIsTextVisible] = useState(false);
  
  return (
     <>
       <button onClick={() => { setIsTextVisible(true) }}>Click on Me!</button>
       { isTextVisible && <p>I am visible only after button click!</p> }
     <>
  )
}
```

In this example, when the button is clicked, the isTextVisible state will be filled with the true value.
When isTextVisible will be equal true - text in condition will be visible.
Text easily can be replaced by another your component.

Comment: Each button would need to render a different component. Would this still work?

Comment: the implementation depends on whether they should work as radiobuttons (hide the content displayed when clicking on other buttons) or whether each button will display only its own content.

If each button will display only its own content, then each of them will need its own state to conditionally render the component associated with the button.

If only one content out of several can be shown at a time, then the state will be one, but it will store the value by which you need to understand which content should be rendered

Comment: Only one content or component, will be shown out of several at a time when any button is clicked.